# .net core mvc client 3.1 authentication and authorization for bearer tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-3.1, bearer-token

I have been reading about authentication and authorization in .net core 3.1 and I am confused.

Basically I have got a .net core MVC app. There is a login view in razor that sends a http request to a web api server and get a token if credentials are correct. Then this bearer token is used for retrieving data from the API. The user credentials are only needed via the login view to get the bearer token and then this token is used to make http request to get and post data.

This is new to me and I don't know what is the best way to do it.

Is it possible to use the token for authenticating and authorizing access to the controllers something like the  signmanager functions and identity?

I have seen ways of storing the user and password, but not sure if it can work for tokens considering that we only use the login to get the bearer token. That is really the only way I can tell a user is logged in.

I am not asking for a project sample as such, but someone who could point me in the right direction. Much appreciated.

Edit:
I forgot to mention the website will be hosted in Azure.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**:

Hope this helps. Trying to be more specific.

I have got an asp.net core mvc web client that calls an API Server to sign in. Username, password and grant_type are sent to the API server using httpclient and this sends a json back with a bearer token, expired and other fields.

I would like to set up the authentication and authorisation based on being able to log in successfully, meaning, calling the API server with url + /token from the login page and the credentials being correct. Keep this token available for the controllers to make other API calls to get and post data to the API server. This way the application knows the user has signed in on the website and I can use the [Authorise} in controllers method to protect them as well as signing out the user, removing the token from the website client.

The client has not got access to a database at the moment, it is just calling the API Server. It is a bit like a mobile app, only uses API calls.

Hope it makes better sense now.

Comment: yes its possible, read about JWT Auth with asp.net core

Comment: Thank you @MuhammadKamranAslam I will have a look. Do you think I can use the login controller to work this way with JWT?

Comment: yes if you ready JWT Auth implementation for asp.net core, you will find tutorials that implement this, you will have to set Claims and use them

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam thank you. I will research it. It looks like is what I needed

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam Hi, I have been looking and all I find how to set up the web api, but not a asp.net core mvc client. Have you got any suggestions on how to search for the client side? I am running out of ideas on how to word it on the search

Comment: What do you want to achieve? as from your description, I am a little vague about what is the actual scenario

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam Hi, I have updated the main post to explain my scenario. It is below "UPDATE:". Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: If you are getting Bearer Token from API, and then want to use that token in another MVC APP, #1 Use Same configs for Token which are being used to generate it. #2 Add JWT Token Auth and Register it in MVC APP. #3 When Token is sent from View to Controller it will get authenticated, or you can make your own Auth Attribute if you want custom permissions etc